# What are the meaning of frozen solve and flexing solve in conda library installations?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When I try to install a package, for instance here geopandas, I have sometimes the following logs :

```
> conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

What does it mean?

Comment: I would guess that `frozen` refers to the same behavior that the flag `--freeze-installed` would show, i.e. not updating/changing anything that is already installed

Comment: It makes sense, thanks!